# Find all packets that contain field name

Tags: wireshark

I'd like to filter all the tcp packets that contain `Server Name Indication` as a field.

This is an example of desired field:

[image]

Usually when I search for contents, I use `frame contains "string"`. This doesn't work here, because `Server Name Indication` is field name, not field value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the examples of [**Display Filters**](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters) that can be applied in WireShark
for Server Name Indication:

- Filter for Server Name Indication as a field: `tls.handshake.extensions_server_name`
- Filter for a specific server name: `tls.handshake.extensions_server_name == "old.reddit.com"`
- Filter for server name containing a string: `tls.handshake.extensions_server_name contains reddit`

To filter with a specific field, single click on the packet in "Packet List"
column. Right click on the field in "Packet Details" column. Select
"Apply as Filter" and "Selected".

[image: wireshark-apply-filters]

### Further details

- [WireShark Wiki: Display Filters](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters)
- [WireShark Docs: Building Display Filter Expressions](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html)